# ruby + selenium-webdriver actionbuilder

Tags: ruby, selenium, automation, selenium-webdriver

I can't seem to get the actionbuilder to work in selenium webdriver.  I am trying to automate a menu that uses Javascript.  I need to mouse over then move and click on a link that appears after the mouse over.

```
$driver.find_element(:id, "top_menu").find_elements(:tag_name, "a").each{ |a|
  if a.attribute('href').include? "javascript"
    then w = a 
    $driver.action.move_to(w).perform
    break
  end
}
```

I realized that my hunt for this element is somewhat vague and not a best practice.  I have already asked for an id for this element.  Any advise on how to use the actionbuilder or a better way to automate mouse movements would be appreciated.

Here is the error I am getting.
`generateErrorForNativeEvents': Cannot perform native interaction: Could not load native events component. (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidElementStateError

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not positive, but I think the update to Firefox 14.0.1 might've broken it. Our tests just broke too. I'm still working on a fix.

UPDATE:
Yeah, I downgraded to Firefox 13.0.1 and my tests are working now.

Comment: hmm well that would be a great coincidence.  The first time I go to use this and it's already broken.  Thanks for the tip.  I'll try it and get back to you.

Comment: alternatively I upgraded Selenium Webdriver gem 2.25.0 That also seems to do the trick

Answer (score 0):

i have faced same problem of InvalidElementStateError: Cannot perform native interaction: Could not load native events component when i was trying to double click on an element

problem was solved when i added following lines

profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new

profile.native_events = false

capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox(:firefox_profile => profile)

@@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, :desired_capabilities => capabilities

Note:- once you do this, Firefox tests will now simulate user interactions via Javascript event firing instead of native clicks. This has its advantages and disadvantages. Hope it helps!